# Geocoder Methods on Json Array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, geocode, rails-geocoder

I am calling some third party API to get locations

```
https://localhost:3000/api/v1/locations
```

this is returning result in json like

```
[{"location_id": 1,"name": "location1" ,"lat": "22.21","long": "-72.54"},{"location_id": 2,"name": "location2","lat": "45.21","long": "-74.21"}]
```

With Active Record we can apply distance filter using Geocoder

```
Location.near([lat, long], 100,units: :km)
```

But API response is json object ,How can I apply distance filter on json object using Geocoder.

Comment: is Location a model where you are storing the api location data?  or just a route you created to fetch it?

Comment: There is no model, its just a route to fetch data from the API,

Comment: I don't have any model or something, just have the API route to fetch the locations from API

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately geocoder does only support ActiveRecord and MongoDB as storage backends but not JSON. With ActiveRecord / Mongo geocoder can also leverage the query language of the database (e.g. SQL) to efficiently find locations near a point. In your case you have now basically two options:

## Store JSON data in ActiveRecord

You could store your JSON data in a database and use ActiveRecord to query the data. There is already a good documentation for this on the gem official GitHub page here https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#geospatial-database-queries.

## Create ActiveRecord like object

If you don't need to store the data from your API request I would recommend to use an Active Record like volatile data storage.

```rb
class Location
  attr_reader :id, :name, :lat, :long

  def initialize(id:, name:, lat:, long:)
    @id = id
    @name = name
    @lat = lat
    @long = long
  end

  def to_coordinates
    [lat.to_f, long.to_f]
  end

  class << self
    attr_accessor :locations

    def from_json(json)
      json.each do |location|
        locations << new(
          id: location[:location_id],
          name: location[:name],
          lat: location[:lat],
          long: location[:long]
        )
      end
    end

    def all
      locations
    end
  end

  self.locations = []
end

json = [
  {"location_id": 1, "name": "location1", "lat": "22.21", "long": "-72.54" },
  {"location_id": 2, "name": "location2", "lat": "45.21", "long": "-74.21" }
]

Location.from_json(json)
puts Location.all
```

We now 'import' your API JSON response and store it in an array as a class attribute in Location. This also has the advantage that you work with objects and not with hashes / JSON anymore.

Now we can create a `near` class method to select all locations close to one point.

```rb
def near(lat, long, radius: 20, units: :km)
  all.select do |location|
    Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(location, [lat, long], units: units) < radius
  end
end
```

The disadvantage here is that we need to iterate over all locations and calculate the distance as we don't have a query language for the JSON data. If performance is an issue, I would suggest to use an SQL database (see previous suggestion).

### Full example

```rb
require "geocoder"

class Location
  attr_reader :id, :name, :lat, :long

  def initialize(id:, name:, lat:, long:)
    @id = id
    @name = name
    @lat = lat
    @long = long
  end

  def to_coordinates
    [lat.to_f, long.to_f]
  end

  class << self
    attr_accessor :locations

    def from_json(json)
      json.each do |location|
        locations << new(
          id: location[:location_id],
          name: location[:name],
          lat: location[:lat],
          long: location[:long]
        )
      end
    end

    def all
      locations
    end

    def near(lat, long, radius: 20, units: :km)
      all.select do |location|
        Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(location, [lat, long], units: units) < radius
      end
    end
  end

  self.locations = []
end

json = [
  {"location_id": 1, "name": "location1", "lat": "22.21", "long": "-72.54" },
  {"location_id": 2, "name": "location2", "lat": "45.21", "long": "-74.21" }
]

Location.from_json(json)

puts Location.near(45.21, -74.21)
```